# What's the reverse of shlex.split?

Tags: python, shell, split, shlex

How can I reverse the results of a [`shlex.split`](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html#shlex.split)? That is, how can I obtain a quoted string that would ["resemble that of a Unix shell"](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html), given a `list` of strings I wish quoted?

### Update0

I've located a Python bug, and made corresponding feature requests [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue9723).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need this if subprocess.Popen takes a list for the command? (when shell=False)

Comment: @tokland: I'm not actually using the output of shlex.split for Popen, I'm parsing a list of paths provided by the user. I allow them to use shell-style splitting.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

We now (3.3) have a [shlex.quote](http://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) function.  It’s none other that `pipes.quote` moved and documented (code using `pipes.quote` will still work).  See http://bugs.python.org/issue9723 for the whole discussion.

`subprocess.list2cmdline` is a private function that should not be used.  It could however be moved to `shlex` and made officially public.  See also http://bugs.python.org/issue1724822.

Comment: What designates `subprocess.list2cmdline()` as private? It is not underscore prefixed, and mentioned in the official documentation!

Comment: `shlex.quote` wont work correctly for chaining commands. i.e. dummy  `cmd = ['pwd', '&&', 'cd']` which yields incorrect command: `"pwd '&&' cd"`.

Comment: `subprocess.list2cmdline()` seems like different command and it behaves correctly with chaining symbols, although it's intended for Windows, where user can pass list to `Popen` anyways (even with enabled shell - `shell=True`)

Comment: Perhaps it would be good to add an actual example of how to use `shlex.quote` to the answer itself? At https://bugs.python.org/issue22454 they suggest using `' '.join(shlex.quote(x) for x in split_command)` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 20):

How about using `pipes.quote`?

```
import pipes
strings = ["ls", "/etc/services", "file with spaces"]
" ".join(pipes.quote(s) for s in strings)
# "ls /etc/services 'file with spaces'"
```

.

Comment: `pipes.quote` is not Windows safe. Windows needs double quotes

Answer (score 13):

It's [shlex.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.join) in python 3.8

Comment: For Python 3.7 or earlier, see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50022816/198219) by Matthijs Kooijman.

Answer (score 11):

There is a feature request for adding `shlex.join()`, which would do exactly what you ask. As of now, there does not seem any progress on it, though, mostly as it would mostly just forward to `shlex.quote()`. In the bug report, a suggested implementation is mentioned:

```
' '.join(shlex.quote(x) for x in split_command)
```

See https://bugs.python.org/issue22454

Comment: That's exactly the implementation currently in Python: [3.9/Lib/shlex.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/shlex.py)

Answer (score 6):

`subprocess` uses `subprocess.list2cmdline()`.  It's not an official public API, but it's mentioned in the `subprocess` documentation and I think it's pretty safe to use.  It's more sophisticated than `pipes.open()` (for better or worse).

Comment: `list2cmdline` is _only used on windows_, so the escaping it performs is only suitable for windows.

Answer (score 0):

While [shlex.quote](http://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) is available in Python 3.3 and [shlex.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.join) is available in Python 3.8, they will not always serve as a true "reversal" of `shlex.split`. Observe the following snippet:

```
import shlex
command = "cd /home && bash -c 'echo $HOME'"
print(shlex.split(command))
# ['cd', '/home', '&&', 'bash', '-c', 'echo $HOME']
print(shlex.join(shlex.split(command)))
# cd /home '&&' bash -c 'echo $HOME'
```

Notice that after splitting and then joining, the `&&` token now has single quotes around it. If you tried running the command now, you'd get an error: `cd: too many arguments`

If you use `subprocess.list2cmdline()` as others have suggested, it works nicer with bash operators like `&&`:

```
import subprocess
print(subprocess.list2cmdline(shlex.split(command)))
# cd /home && bash -c "echo $HOME"
```

However you may notice now that the quotes are now double instead of single. This results in `$HOME` being expanded by the shell rather than being printed verbatim as if you had used single quotes.

In conclusion, there is no 100% fool-proof way of undoing `shlex.split`, and you will have to choose the option that best suites your purpose and watch out for edge cases.