# How to converts a list of arguments into single string command line in Python?

Tags: python, escaping, argv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the reverse of shlex.split?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748344/whats-the-reverse-of-shlex-split)

How do I convert a list of command line parameters, like `argv` to a single string for command line?

`" ".join(argv)` is not the correct solution as it will not escape the strings with spaces correctly.

Example: `./test.py -v --simulate --action removePage  --title "AAA BBB"`

If you try this the last argument is `AAA BBB` without quotes but if I try to rebuild the command line with join I will get a wrong result.

Note: I know that I can get the command line as a string, but in my case I cannot rely on that, I need a solution that converts a list of arguments to a proper command line.

Comment: So you want the inverse of `shlex.split`?

Comment: What do you want to do with the string you're building?

Comment: note: '*argv' doesnt unpack arguments - its the '*' that does it. So you could do *a, *aa, *hello, etc.

Answer (score 2):

With Python 3.3 you can try using [`shlex.quote`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) (sorry, I can't check):

```
' '.join(shlex.quote(arg) for arg in argv)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if you don't mind gratuitous quoting:

```
" ".join('"%s"'%x.strip().replace('"',r'\"') for x in lst)
```